# What replaces class variables in scala?

Tags: scala, static

In Java I sometimes use class variables to assign a unique ID to each new instance. I do something like

```java
public class Foo {

  private static long nextId = 0;

  public final long id;

  public Foo() {
    id = nextId;
    nextId++;
  }

  [...]

}
```

How can I do this in Scala?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Variables on the companion object:

```
object Foo{
    private var current = 0
    private def inc = {current += 1; current}
}

class Foo{
    val i = Foo.inc
    println(i)
}
```

Answer (score 27):

To amplify on Thomas' answer:

The `object` definition is usually put in the same file with the class, and *must* have the same name. This results in a single instance of an object having the name of the class, which contains whatever fields you define for it.

A handy do-it-yourself Singleton construction kit, in other words.

At the JVM level, the object definition actually results in the definition of a new class; I think it's the same name with a `$` appended, e.g. `Foo$`. Just in case you have to interoperate some of this stuff with Java.

Comment: Objects don't have to have the same name as classes, only _companion objects_ do.

Comment: We tend to use the same name for class and object , as it helps a lot in Debugging the Code.

Comment: These two answers should be combined