# Scala: Why can't I increment the int like this?

Tags: scala

The Item class has an instance variable id that starts with 0. I want to call nextID to increment the id from 0 to 1; however, when i do new Item().id += 1, there is a type mismatch. Why is that?

```
class Item {
 private var id: Int = 0
 this.id = Item.nextId
}
// companion object
object Item{
 def apply() = new Item()
 def nextId: Int = {
   new Item().id += 1  //type mismatch
 }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this `this.id = Item.nextId`?

Comment: I think `+=` returns `Unit` so that's why you have a type mismatch, but that's not the only problem you have here

Comment: @nbro This is actually my homework assignment. According to the instruction i should create a private static nextId variable that stores the next available id number. The Item constructor could use this to initialize id, then increment the variable. Scala doesn't have static variables. So I declared nextId in the Item companion object.

Comment: @2rs2ts Can you point out the other problems I have?

Comment: @user21478621 I'm not sure, but `nextId` is supposed to return an `Int`, but  this expression `new Item().id += 1 ` returns `Unit`, because that's what `+=` returns. Check this post for a possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888716/what-replaces-class-variables-in-scala. Moreover, I do not think you have to create a new Item inside `nextId`.

Comment: @user21478621 you are not storing the nextId number anywhere, but you are correct that it belongs in the companion object.  Your item class should probably take id as a constructor parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where to begin?

```
def nextId: Int = {
  new Item().id += 1
}
```

`+=` is an assignment. Assignments don't have return values but `nextId` is supposed to be an `Int`. We might fix it like this...

```
def nextId: Int = {
  val nitem = new Item()
  nitem.id += 1
  nitem.id
}
```

...but there are other problems. Every time someone invokes `nextId` it creates a new `Item`, that Item's `id` is incremented, the updated value of this `id` is returned, and the new `Item` is thrown away.  That doesn't sound right.

```
class Item {
  private var id: Int = 0
  this.id = Item.nextId
}
```

Hmm, this looks suspicious. When an `Item` is created it calls `nextId`, but `nextId` creates a new `Item`, which is going to call `nextId`, which creates a new `Item`, which calls .... where will it all end?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! When I was doing nextId, I am not sure how I can mutate the id in Item without creating a new Item. Do you have any hints for me how to fix this?

Comment: Make the instance `id` a `val`. Initialize it to the only value it will ever have when it is created. The companion object should hold the `private var` that is the id counter. Then all that `nextId()` has to do is increment the counter and return the new value.

Comment: Thank you so much :) That helps a lot!!