# scala class members causing error "Class 'class' must either be declared abstract or implement member 'member' "

Tags: java, scala, class, functional-programming, member

I am trying to learn **Scala** [Object](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-scala/9781449368814/ch09.html#objects_section)s and [Class](https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/132.html). I come from **Java** which is quite similar to Scala, but not in syntax.

In **Java**, I would create a class like:

```
public class Wallet {
    private PublicKey publicKey;
    private PrivateKey privateKey;
    private int balance = 0;

    public Wallet() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
        publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
    }

    public int getBalance(){
        return balance;
    }
}
```

This defines the template of a `Wallet` object, which I can instantiate in **Java** as:

```
Wallet wallet = new Wallet();
```

This will also create a `PrivateKey` and `PublicKey` in the `Wallet` constructor and assign it to the corresponding class members.

I understand that **Scala** uses a slightly difference approach, where classes are simply templates of instantiatable objects, and `Object`s are `Singleton` type objects that store information persistently.

Also, I found that an `Object` is frequently used in a `Class` file as a *Companion Object* according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888716/what-replaces-class-variables-in-scala).

Using the above `Wallet` example, I am attempting to recreate this in **Scala**. This is what I have so far:

```
class Wallet {

  var publicKey: PublicKey
  var privateKey: PrivateKey
  var balance: Int = 0

  def this() {
    this
    val keyPair =  KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("SHA-256").generateKeyPair()
    privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate
    publicKey = keyPair.getPublic
  }

  def getBalance(): Int = {
    balance
  }
}
```

**The problem:**

> Class 'Wallet' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract
>   member 'publicKey: PublicKey' in 'com.simple.blockchain.Wallet

*Now this is confusing to me.*

In **Java**, this would normally to be a problem to have declared but uninstantiated objects as class members, so if I try adding a *Companion Object* as suggested in the earlier SO post and following their suggestion with:

```
object Wallet {
  var privateKey: PrivateKey
  var publicKey: PublicKey
}
```

I get an error:

> Only classes can have declared but undefined members

**TL;DR**

I would like to have the `Wallet` **Java** code to **Scala** code, how could I achieve this?

---

**UPDATE (to clarify my original question)**

So, the answer do not reflect my actual question (what I had in mind). I will attempt to clarify.

There are various constructors supported by Scala.

Primary constructors you will find as mentioned by @Josh [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54856681/4628115)

```
class Person(name: String) {
    var personName: String = name
}
```

and secondary constructors will be (by extending @Josh's example) such as:

```
def this() {
    this("Unknown Person Name")
    // additional code
}
```

These constructors are discussed [here in some detail](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-create-multiple-class-constructors-in-scala-alternate-constructors), it makes for a good read.

**What I am interested in is this.**

As I have declared a member `privateKey` and `publicKey`, so I wish to declare more members in my class. Not all these members will be instantiated when the class is initialized, but will be later during the application's execution.

This below will give more context to what I described above. I will instantiate the `Wallet`, and at a later stage call `wallet.generateKeys()`.

```
class Wallet {

  var publicKey: PublicKey
  var privateKey: PrivateKey
  var balance: Int = 0

  def generateKeys(): Unit = {
    val keyPair =  KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("SHA-256").generateKeyPair()
    privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate
    publicKey = keyPair.getPublic
  }

  def getBalance(): Int = {
    balance
  }
}
```

This will require a variable declared, but uninstantiated during runtime, up until the point where it is needed.

How will **this** be defined in Scala code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to have values that are not initialised when the object is created, it is best to make them `Option` values:

```
class Wallet {
  private var publicKey: Option[PublicKey] = None
  private var privateKey: Option[PrivateKey] = None
  private var balance: Int = 0

  def generateKeys(): Unit = {
    val keyPair =  KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("SHA-256").generateKeyPair()
    privateKey = Some(keyPair.getPrivate)
    publicKey = Some(keyPair.getPublic)
  }

  def getBalance = balance
}
```

This is safer than using `null` because the type system and runtime will check that the value is valid when you use it.

But the other answers are correct that it is better to defer creating this object until the keys are available, if possible.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to do this, but [it's a code smell](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/334970/are-init-methods-a-code-smell). Suppose somebody makes an instance of your Wallet. They have to call `generateKeys` before your class is really usable. If they forget and try to use the keys, they will get a runtime error or nonsensical behavior. Instead, set these in the main constructor (as [Josh suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54856681/2093695)) or a factory/apply method (as [Andy suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54856791/2093695)).

### If you want to do it anyway

If you really want to have a declared but uninitialized field...you can't, exactly, not even in Java. In Java, uninitialized fields are implicitly initialized to a default value (`null` for objects). You can get this behavior in Scala by assigning an underscore (`_`) to it:

```
var publicKey: PublicKey = _
var privateKey: PrivateKey = _
```

These will be initialized to null. Please don't do this, though.

### Other issues with your code

1. In Scala, you should prefer `val` to `var`.
2. All of your variables are public. I'm guessing you at least meant to make `balance` private, since you also have a `getBalance` method.
3. Your `Person` example doesn't follow idiomatic style, since you can just write it as `class Person(var personName: String)`.

Comment: [ScalaTest recommends assigning to underscore in their docs.](https://www.scalatest.org/scaladoc/1.8/org/scalatest/BeforeAndAfter.html) Is unit testing an exception to the practice? If not, how would you structure your tests to be more idiomatic?

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of the `def this() { ... }`. In scala, the constructor body is just the lines of code after the class declaration. Like this:

```
class Person(name: String) {
    private val id: String = name

    // ... other fields, methods, etc.
}
```

Comment: I am aware of this, but this is not what I had intended at all. If this were the case, you should see something in the Wallet constructor like `public Wallet(int balance) { this.balance = balance; }`, however this is not the case. I do not want to pass in any paramaters, I wish to instantiate parameters to assist instantiating my Wallet object.

Comment: Right, but just do your assignments to `publicKey` and `privateKey` right there where they are declared. No need to add another constructor. Essentially, take the body of `this()` that you have and inline it.

Comment: thank you for your answer, please see my question update as this may provide more clarify to what I am asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an apply on the companion object:

```scala
class Wallet private (val privateKey: PrivateKey, publicKey: PublicKey, balance: Int) {
  def getBalance(): Int = balance
}
object Wallet {
  def apply(): Wallet = {
    val keyPair =  KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("SHA-256").generateKeyPair()
    val privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate
    val privateKey = keyPair.getPublic
    new Wallet(privateKey, privateKey, 0)
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, please see my question update as this may provide more clarify to what I am asking.

Comment: @KGCybeX using var is an scala anti-pattern, so I don't think you want this generateKeys method.